# How do I serve all paths under a SUBDIRECTORY to a single PHP file using nginx?

Tags: nginx, php

I have the following structure

```
/var/www/lsl/generalmedia
    subcontent1/
         picture.jpg
    subcontent2/
         subsub1/
             picture.jpg
         subsub2/
    index.php
```

Accessible via `website.com/lsl/generalmedia`

I would like to make the subdirectories use the same index.php file, but serve files normally. Examples:

`website.com/lsl/generalmedia/subcontent1` needs to call `lsl/generalmedia/index.php`

`website.com/lsl/generalmedia/subcontent1/picture.jpg` must open the picture in your browser.

I have tried the following, but I'm getting 403 forbidden whenever I go to a subdirectory:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/;
    index index.php;
    server_name _;

    location /lsl/generalmedia/ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @nested;
            location ~ \.php$ {
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/lsl/generalmedia/index.php;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            }
    }

    location @nested{
            rewrite /lsl/generalmedia/(.*)$ /lsl/generalmedia/index.php?/$1 last;
    }


    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: What's in the error log?

Comment: @Tom I'm updating an old asset browser which needs to be able to explore folders under lsl/generalmedia in a slightly better looking way than standard old indexes

Comment: Try: `try_files $uri @nested;` - and you can remove the nested `location ~ \.php$` block as it's never invoked.

Comment: @RichardSmith yep that's what was tripping it. I rewrote it to just `try_files $uri /lsl/generalmedia/index.php?$args;` so I wouldn't need the @nested location. I'm assuming it's because $uri/ tries to fetch the location, and since it doesn't have an index file it throws a 403 error? Feel free to post it as an answer, because it did what I was after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$uri/` term in the `try_files` statement causes Nginx to test for the existence of a directory. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Because `subcontent1` is a directory, Nginx processes it according to its `index` directive. The 403 response is because there is no `index.php` file within that subdirectory.

Remove that term, for example:

```
location /lsl/generalmedia/ {
    try_files $uri @nested;
}
```

Also, the nested location block is never visited as **any** URI ending with `.php` is currently processed by the `location ~ \.php$` block at the end of your configuration.

---

If the specific rewrite in the @nested block is not required, the default PHP file can be specified in the same statement. For example:

```
location /lsl/generalmedia/ {
    try_files $uri /lsl/generalmedia/index.php?$args;
}
```